# How can I prevent amending a commit when in the middle of a merge conflict?

Tags: git

My workflow usually involves uploading commits for review e.g. commit chain `A(HEAD) -> B -> C` - and if I get a review on commit `B` - I run `git rebase -i`, select `B` for editing, and then run `git commit --amend` followed by `git rebase --continue` to patch the commit with fixes in-place in the chain.

This is the common flow, but sometimes - when I edit `B` I get a merge conflict in `A`.

The way an interactive rebase workflow is **supposed** to work is that I resolve the conflicts, stage them with `git add` - and then run `git rebase --continue` *without amending the commit*.

However, the merge-conflict-free `git commit --amend` flow is so common that I often find myself making the absentminded mistake of running `git commit --amend; git rebase --continue` instead of `git rebase --continue` - which wreaks havoc on my chain, squashing two commits together and I then need to delve into `git reflog` to unsquash them.

---

This is almost **never** the desired behavior, and is usually a mistake - it's rare that someone would want to amend a new commit with resolved merge conflicts into the previous commit.

Is there a way to configure git to disallow amending a commit when in the middle of a merge conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During rebase, there is a `.git/rebase-merge` directory. `--amend` can be captured in the hook [prepare-commit-msg](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg).

> or commit, followed by a commit object name (if a -c, -C or --amend
> option was given).

So one of the ideas is to fail `prepare-commit-msg` and abort the commit if `.git/rebase-merge` exists and `--amend` is used. In order to bypass the test, we can define a config value, `foo.bar`.

A demo in Bash,

```
#!/bin/bash

msg_file=$1
msg_source=$2
msg_object=$3

foo_bar=$(git config --get foo.bar)
if [[ "${foo_bar}" != "false" ]];then
    gitdir=$(git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir)
    rebase_dir=${gitdir}/rebase-merge

    if [[ -d "${rebase_dir}" ]] && [[ "$msg_source" = commit ]];then
        echo "Forbid 'git commit --amend' during rebase"
        echo "Maybe you want 'git rebase --continue'?"
        echo "If you do want to amend during rebase, use 'git -c foo.bar=false commit --amend'"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

The side effect is that `git commit -C $commit` or `git commit -c $commit` during rebase are also failed. But we can bypass it with `-c foo.bar=false`.

Comment: Awesome! I had a similar idea of using a `post-rewrite` based hook alongside a `pre-commit`  hook to maintain merge/rebase-based state (by e.g looking at `.git/MERGE_HEAD` / `.git/REBASE_HEAD` and maintaining a `.git/REBASE_MERGE` file) but funnily enough I completely missed the existence of `.git/rebase_merge`! That makes the hook much simpler to write - and indeed your demo hook looks great, thanks

Comment: Another way to bypass the hook without needing a config value is to always have the hook turned "on" by default (no `foo.bar` configuration at all) - and using `git commit --no-verify`

Comment: @DanielKleinstein `--no-verify` affects the pre-commit and commit-msg hooks. The prepare-commit-msg hook is not affected.

Comment: True - but it's enough to make use of a pre-commit hook for this functionality - I don't think you'll be able to discern that `--amend` was used for the commit, but it's not strictly necessary, it makes sense to invoke this logic for *all* commit types. And the `--no-verify` flag means that you can easily override the logic